# How can I make a separate database in django and not use the default database?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, google-authentication

Okay, so I am a complete newbie and this might be a silly question but I couldn't find any answer related to this. I have created a login page using google authentication using django-allauth and it works perfectly fine but the problem it saves the user data directly into default database but I want it to be stored in my own mysql database.

I changed the default database info in the settings.py file but when I open the site to login I get an error "Social query does not exist". Is there any other changes that I need to do other than changing the default database in  settings.py?

DATABASES = {

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mysql',
    'USER' : '****',
    'PASSWORD' : '****',
    'HOST' : 'localhost',
    'PORT' : 3306
}
```

}

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for multiple db setup? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/ - You can define multiple DB endpoints (2 mysqls for example) and _choose_ which to use when working with your model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset

Comment: @Glycerine I am sorry but that's not exactly what I am looking for. I think I was unable to explain it properly. I have edited it, now you will get what I am trying to say.

Comment: Did you run the migrations after changing the DATABASES settings? `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @MarcCompte Yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to run py manage.py migrate for to make the new tables on the data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).